# Sailsjs Model Object Not Returning Data For Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I have the following in my Sailsjs **config/adapter.js**:

```
module.exports.adapters = {
  'default': 'postgres',

  postgres : {
   module   : 'sails-postgresql',
   host     : 'xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
   port     : 5432,
   user     : 'xxx',
   password : 'xxx',
   database : 'xxx',
   ssl      : true,
   schema   : true

  }
};
```

And in **models/Movie.js**:

```
 Movie = {

  attributes: {
    tableName: 'movies.movies',
    title: 'string',
    link: 'string'
  }

};

module.exports = Movie;
```

In my **controller**:

```
Movie.query("SELECT * FROM movies.movies", function(err, movies) {
  console.log('movies', movies.rows);
});
```

movies.rows **DOES** return the correct data

However:

```
  Movie.find({ title: 'Frozen' }, function(err, movies) {
    console.log('movies', movies)
  });
```

movies returns an **EMPTY ARRAY**

So it seems all connections are good because the raw query works perfectly.

Could there be something I am doing wrong with setting up the Movie.find() or with models/Movie.js?

Does the tableName attribute not support postgresql schema_name.table_name?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to move `tableName` out of `attributes`, since it's a class-level property.  Second, `sails-postgresql` does have some (very undocumented) support for schemas, using the `meta.schemaName` option:

```
Movie = {

  tableName: 'movies',
  meta: {
     schemaName: 'movie'
  },

  attributes: {
    title: 'string',
    link: 'string'
  }

};

module.exports = Movie;
```

You can give that a try, and if it doesn't work, either move your table into the `public` schema, or [nudge the author of the `schemaName` support](https://github.com/Zolmeister) for help.

Comment: It keeps saving records under public schema, regardless of what schemaName is provided. Am I missing anything? 

    User.create({name:'Diego'}).exec(function createCB(err, created){
      console.log('Created user with name ' + created.name);
    });